# URLFOR Button Open then Close Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, urlfor

I created a Visulforce Page that generates a word document.I have a button that opens the Visualforce Page where it Displays in existing window without sidebar with the Button or Link URL below:

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/vfEUD_Template2", "", [id=SBQQ__Quote__c.Id])}
```

Is it possible to have the page open, where the Word document is rendered and then page close to go back to there it was.

Comment: Use the Open In New Window option?

Comment: I could but it comes up as a blank page. Is it possible to automatically have the window close?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I think this is a browser setting. I'm not sure you can control it directly in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes I noticed. I tried in my constructor to call PageReference and either use Javascript to close window or redirect to original page. This did not work. I then tried to use an action in the VP setting to close window... Nothing works.